# Simplest means to develop relational database for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, rdbms

For those of you have have experience of this, what particular tools would you recommend?

- MS Access
- MS Visual Studio
- SQL Management Studio
- etc?

For use with SQL Server 2008 R2 as part of an online booking system with multiple tables and relationships, and incorporated into an ASP.Net site.

Comment: I'd edit the question to make it <quote>more clear</quote> only superfluity is something we already have in abundance on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both SQL Management Studio and Visual Studio are good options. With Visual Studio you can work with the database and your projects in one window. You can do most basic database operations in Visual Studio. SQL Management gives you additional options and flexibility like backing up database wizard, SQL Profiler, Execution Plan

Comment: Thanks. My two concerns are the ease of development of the db (in particular, relationships and queries) but also in the manipulation of the db by the ASP.Net site itself. Whilst the former would be more straightforward through the use of SSMS I am concerned that its use could incur additional complexity when writing the C# accompanying the site  (which will be dev'd in Visual Studio). Is this concern largely unjustified?

Comment: there is no complexity involved. the only concern is switching between Visual Studio and SSMS windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with SQL Management Studio. I've worked with it before and it met all demands, and didn't have any problems. And I would think with SQL Server 2008 R2 it wold be a safe choice.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague, so I'm going to give an answer that is probably a little more broad than you need.

TL;DR - SSMS gives a great development environment for databases.

Typically, when building a new system, I design my data structures on a whiteboard.  Once these are pretty well defined, I put them into SQL using SSMS's table designer, including Primary Keys and Foreign Keys, but no additional indexes.

Once I have the basic layout defined, I'll generate a Database Diagram, print it out, and review to make sure 1) I've built the system as defined, and 2) I don't see any glaring items that are missing.  Assuming no issues, I'll start development.

At this point, if I want to use Entity Framework, I can just use the DB-First method, and I'm ready to go.  If I want to use an alternate method, such as DataReaders/DataSets, I'm also good to go.

Any views, stored procedures, etc I build by hand inside of SSMS.

I leave out indexes until a good portion of the functionality is complete, so as to not prematurely create indexes that end up giving no value.